# How to differentiate between $(\lambda_{0}-\lambda)^{k} \,\text{and } g(\lambda) \,\text{in } f_{A}(\lambda)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

By definition, $\lambda_{0}$ has algebraic multiplicity $k$ if $\lambda_{0}$ is a root of $f_{A}(\lambda)=(\lambda_{0}-\lambda)^{k}g(\lambda)$. What am I missing from this?

---

$f_{A}(\lambda)=\lambda(\lambda+1)(\lambda-1)^{2}\\\rightarrow\left\{\lambda_{1}=0\, | \,\text{almu}(\lambda_{1})=1\right\},\left\{\lambda_{2}=-1\, | \,\text{almu}(\lambda_{2})=1\right\},\left\{\lambda_{3}=1\, | \,\text{almu}(\lambda_{3})=2\right\}$

$f_{B}(\lambda)=-(\lambda+1)(\lambda^{2}+1)\rightarrow \left\{\lambda=-1\, | \,\text{almu}(\lambda)=1\right\}\\f_{C}(\lambda)=-(\lambda-1)(\lambda^{2}+\lambda+1)\rightarrow \left\{\lambda=1\, | \,\text{almu}(\lambda)=1\right\}\\f_{D}(\lambda)=-\lambda^{2}(\lambda+3)\rightarrow \left\{\lambda_{1}=0\, | \,\text{almu}(\lambda_{1})=2\right\},\left\{\lambda_{2}=-3\, | \,\text{almu}(\lambda_{2})=1\right\}$

---

I have a sinking feeling that my issue largely has to do with the elementary exercise of finding the roots of polynomials, but I really don't understand this:  $$\text{for }f_{B}(\lambda) \,\text{and } f_{C}(\lambda),\text{almu}(\lambda)=1, \text{but for }f_{D}(\lambda),\text{almu}(\lambda_{1})=2.$$ Is it because $(\lambda^{2}+1) \,\text{and } (\lambda^{2}+\lambda+1)$ have no real roots?

I can give myself nice heuristics like "if the exponent on lambda is part of a product, that's almu; if the exponent on lambda is part of a sum, it doesn't matter", but this seems sloppy.

How do I differentiate between  $f_{A}(\lambda)=(\lambda_{0}-\lambda)^{k}$ and $g(\lambda)$? It seems like they can be both any real-valued function.

---

### Related notational/formatting questions:

- How can I illustrate these relationships without writing almu all the time?
- Is it customary to use subscripts for $\lambda \iff \exists \,\text{more  
     than one eigenvalue}?$
- Can $\text{almu}(\lambda)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - *Definition*:
>
>   The definition of the *algebraic multiplicity* $k$ of a root $\lambda_0$ of a function $f_A$ additionally contains that $k$ is *maximal*. So, 
>     \begin{align*}
>   f_A(\lambda)=(\lambda-\lambda_0)^kg(\lambda)\quad\text{and}\quad g(\lambda_0)\ne 0\tag{1}
>   \end{align*}
> - *Roots:*
>
>   The roots $\lambda_0$ are elements of the *domain* of $f_A$. According to the domain, typically $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, you have to search for complex or real roots.
> - *Notational conventions:*
>
>   Due to the maximality property of $k$, we always have $\text{almu}(\lambda_0)=k$. Therefore the value $k$ in (1) already provides the information about the *algebraic multiplicity* of the root $\lambda_0$.
>
>   It's only a matter of convenience to use either subscripts or different names without indices for the roots. Usually we might use index notation if there are more than one or two roots.
>
>   The *[multiplicity of a root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_%28mathematics%29#Multiplicity_of_a_root_of_a_polynomial)*  of a polynomial is always a natural number $\geq 1$.

Comment: @BenjaminLoya: Thanks a lot for granting the bounty and accepting my answer. Best regards,